# Spring batch Custom count based on some logic

Tags: spring-batch

In processor,

I call third-party System and based on the response I am increasing success or failure count. I want to write both counts to log file. How to know that JOB completed from the processor?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> How to know that JOB completed from the processor?

Well, if you are in the processor, this means the job is still running. Do you agree?

What you can do is add the metrics in the job execution context (or step execution context) from within the processor and register a `JobExecutionListener` that reads those metrics from the execution context and write them to a log file after the job is finished (see [JobExecutionListener#afterJob](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/api/org/springframework/batch/core/JobExecutionListener.html#afterJob-org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecution-)).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Mahmoud Ben Hassine.

Comment: Thanks, Mahmoud Ben Hassine.
Can you please tell me How to add the metrics in the job execution context from within the processor?
I have already register JobExecutionListener.

Comment: You can make your item processor implement `ItemStream` and add the metrics to the execution context in the `update(ExecutionContext executionContext)` method. You can also add a method annotated with `BeforeStep` or `AfterStep` to get access to the step execution(see example in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/4.0.x/reference/html/common-patterns.html#passingDataToFutureSteps)